# Under what circumstances will RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String) return null?

Tags: .net, exception, registry

So the doco for `RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad51f2dx(v=vs.110).aspx says

> Return Value: The newly created subkey, or null if the operation failed. If a zero-length string is specified for subkey, the current RegistryKey object is returned.

However looking at the exception list

- ArgumentNullException: when subkey is null.
- SecurityException: When The user does not have the permissions required to create or open the registry key.
- ObjectDisposedException:When The RegistryKey on which this method is being invoked is closed (closed keys cannot be accessed).
- UnauthorizedAccessException: When The RegistryKey cannot be written to; for example, it was not opened as a writable key , or the user does not have the necessary access rights.
- IOException: When The nesting level exceeds 510. -or- A system error occurred, such as deletion of the key, or an attempt to create a key in the LocalMachine root.

I cant think of a failure condition that would not fall into one of those exception cases.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ignore this, it doesn't actually happen.  The underlying problem is that the native winapi functions for the registry are very unusual.  And don't in fact guarantee that the returned handle isn't null.  Putting it in C# terms, a "normal" winapi function is used like this:

```
HANDLE handle = CreateWidget(...);
if (handle == NULL) {
    int err = GetLastError();
    DealWithError(err);
}
```

But the registry functions work like this:

```
HANDLE handle;
int err = RegCreateKeyEx(..., out handle);
if (err != 0) DealWithError(err);
```

You probably see the difference, in the normal case there's a very hard guarantee that the handle won't be null if the function failed.  But the registry functions allow the loophole of returning a null handle but still returning a 0 error code.  The MSDN documentation cannot exclude that possibility because the winapi documentation doesn't exclude it.

In practice this never happens, an error code is always produced.

Not sure what the original reason behind this design quirk might be.  We need Raymond Chen to blog about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `CreateSubKey()` in the reference source, there's only one code path that may return null:
When [RegCreateKeyEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns 0 (ERROR_SUCCESS), but the resulting key handle (`phkResult` output parameter) is invalid (`INVALID_HANDLE` or `NULL`).

That code path contains an assertion:

```
BCLDebug.Assert(false, "Unexpected code path in RegistryKey::CreateSubKey");
```

So I guess this means that `CreateSubKey()` should never returns null.
Maybe the MSDN documentation was just copy-pasted from `OpenSubKey`, which returns null when the key is missing?